# Jquery Function

Tags: jquery, function, onchange

I am using the below code to set the character count on a textarea. This solution is working fine as far as i am passing the textarea ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var charactersAllowed = 255; // this is picked from widget configuration
        $("#charCount").html(charactersAllowed);
        $("#message").keyup(function() {
            $("#charCount").html(charactersAllowed - ($(this).val().length));
            if($(this).val().length > charactersAllowed) {
                this.value = this.value.substring(0, charactersAllowed);
                $("#charCount").html(charactersAllowed - ($(this).val().length));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" tabindex="4" rows="4" cols="35"></textarea>
    <p class="character_limit">Character limit: <span id="charCount"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

what i need to do is to wrap this functionality in function so that i can call this function on any input element. 
Can i wrap the same code inside a function name and call the same function on Textarea onchange() event?

Please provide me the inputs & help to recode this snippet.

Thanks
Lokesh Yadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply what you have to any text area:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    limitTextBox("#message", "#charCount", 255);
});

function limitTextBox(box, charsDisplay, charactersAllowed) {
    var $box = $(box),
        $charsDisplay = $(charsDisplay);
    $charsDisplay.html(charactersAllowed - ($box.val().length));
    $box.keyup(function() {
        $charsDisplay.html(charactersAllowed - ($box.val().length));
        if($box.val().length > charactersAllowed) {
            $box[0].value = $box[0].value.substring(0, charactersAllowed);
            $charsDisplay.html(charactersAllowed - ($box.val().length));
        }
    });

}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/utuqi4)

...but can I strongly recommend that you **don't do that**. Look instead at how StackOverflow limits input into text boxes (such as comments). They let you type whatever you want, but only actually let you save your comment if you're within range. This truncating the content as people type makes for a *terrible* user experience.

**Off-topic**: In your original function, sometimes you used `val()` on a jQuery instance, other times you used `value` on the raw DOM element. I've preserved that above, but you probably want to pick one or the other and use it throughout.

Comment: very true T.J. But the thing is it's a client's requirement.

Comment: i will surely present your opinion to my manager to rethink on this implementation. your point makes sense in terms of user experience, thanks for responding so quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a plugin like so:

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.charlimit = function(options) {
       var def = {limit: 250, display: null};
       $.extend(def, options);
       var $display = $(def.display);

       $display.html(def.limit);

       this.bind('change keyup', function() {
            var l = $(this).val().length;
            $display.html(def.limit - l);
            if(l > def.limit) {
                $(this).val(function(i, value) {
                     return value.substring(0, def.limit);
                });
                $display.html(def.limit - $(this).val().length);
            }
       });
       return this; 
   };   
}(jQuery));
```

And use it with:

```
$('#message').charlimit({limit: 250, display: '#charCount'});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ETFyv/)

Comment: @Lokesh: You're welcome :) I'm not saying that this code is optimal though ;) One problem is that if you are applying the method on several elements (i.e. the selectors selects multiple elements), then they all share the same "`display `" element (which shows the character count). So either you apply this function only to single elements (one after another) or you somehow fix it to support multiple "`display`" elements.

Comment: i do not know if i made a mistake while incorporating your code.... whenever charcount become 0 then if i press any key again,.... charcount will go to -60 and showing function(i, value){} inside the textarea

Comment: @Lokesh: Mmh. I cannot reproduce this in my demo. Can you? If yes, then there is some error in the code. If not.... you made a mistake somewhere. Does the selector select one or multiple elements?

Comment: i placed only one textarea control on my page,

Comment: @Lokesh: You mean what I type into the text field? I just press random keys :D

Comment: what exactly i did, i placed the plugin code in a seperate js file named as charcount.js....... then i called the charcount function on (document).ready ... on html page itself under <script> tag.

Comment: @Lokesh: I assume you included the filer *after* jQuery? (otherwise it would not work anyway). Do you see any error message at the console?

Comment: if you don'd mind .. please share your email id with me.. i will mail you the zip file ... only if you are ok with sharing you email over here .. otherwise no worries :)

Comment: @Lokesh: Mmh, I'm thinking about a better way... can't you just upload the file somewhere where I can download it? Or better create some live example for me :)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
(function($) {
$.fn.charlimit = function(options) {
var def = {
limit: 250,
display: null
};
$.extend(def, options);
var $display = $(def.display);
$display.html(def.limit);
this.bind('change keyup', function() {
var l = $(this).val().length;
$display.html(def.limit - l);
if (l > def.limit) {
$(this).val(function(i, value) {
return value.substring(0, def.limit);
});
$display.html(def.limit - $(this).val().length);
}
});
return this;
};
}(jQuery));
$('#message').charlimit({
Limit: 10,
display: '#charCount'
});
});
</script>

Comment: i used the above script tag on my html page

Comment: @Lokesh: That is exactly the same as my code (also you have to write `limit` small in `.charlimit({Limit:...`. Sorry, everything looks fine. Which browser and jQuery version are you using?

Comment: @Lokesh: I don't know if it is such a good idea to create a new question for this.... you should better answer my questions ;) Which browser do you use and which jQuery version?

Comment: i am getting the same error in IE also... recently checked on IE7/8 both

Comment: @Lokesh: See, you should have told me that earlier. The possibility to pass functions to `val()` was added in jQuery 1.4. You have to change this part to: `$(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, def.limit));`. Now I suggest you delete the other question and give me at least an up vote ;)

Comment: thanks a lot Felix, i think i should update my jQuery to 1.5... :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a class (in my example "myclass") on the textareas you want to check and modify this:

```
$("#message").keyup(function() { ...
```

Into this:

```
$("textarea.myclass").keyup(function() { ...
```

and

```
$("#charCount")
```

To

```
$(this).find('span.charCount')
```

Of course you have to edit your HTML and change the span ID to a class (thx @T.J. Crowder for pointing it out!)

Comment: Which does nothing whatsoever for all of the id-specific selectors inside his `keyup` function.

Comment: then i have to define classname on textarea. My question was like can i put onchange=sonefunction(this); on textarea and pass the reference to jquery function.

Comment: You really don't want to use that, trust me ;-) Don't mix your content, presentation and JS altogether. By calling the function on the right selector from your JS file, you separate things nicely. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: this links contains so much useful information... thanks a lot Capsule :)